# auto как аргумент функции

Tags: c++, c++14

Я знаю, что в стандарте `C++ 14` возможно использовать ключевое слово `auto` при указании типа аргумента.

Но мне не понятно, по каким правилам это работает? 
Функция будет работать как шаблонная?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В C++14 `auto` при описании типа аргумента можно использовать только в лямбда-выражениях. И да, эффект такого использования `auto` фактически сводится к тому, что метод `operator ()` соответствующего функционального объекта станет шаблонным методом.

Т.е.

```
[](auto x) { return x + 1; }
```

порождает лямбда-класс, выглядящий примерно как

```
struct Lambda123 {
  ...
  template <typename T> auto operator ()(T x) const { return x + 1; }
  ...
};
```